# How to trigger a Bootstrap Template accordion style menu from a link outside the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wondering if anybody could help. I'm using a Bootstrap Template from wrapbootstrap, called "Black Pearl". It contains a dropdown style menu that is structured like the below; It creates a menu with options, and you can specify submenus which drop down when the main option is clicked - as per example below. "Customers" is the main heading, and "New Cutomer" drops down when customers is clicked.

```
<ul class="side-menu shadowed">
    <li> <a class="navmenu" url="login.php?" href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="submenu"> <a href=""><i class="icon-address-book"></i>Customers</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" url="cust_new.php?" class="navmenu">New Customer</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The javascript which i think runs this...

```
/* --------------------------------------------------------
    Side Menu
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
(function(){
     $('.side-menu > li.submenu > a').unbind();
    $('.side-menu > li.submenu > a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).next('ul').is(":visible")) {
    $('.side-menu > li ul').slideUp(150);
    $(this).next('ul').slideDown(150);
    }
    else {
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle(150);
    }


    });
})();
```

Anyone have any ideas how i could toggle the menu change from a link outside the menu?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the target `menu` trigger and programatically trigger a click event...

like if you want to trigger the customers menu, for easy selection of the element add a Class to the anchor element as given below

```
<li class="submenu"><a href="" class="customers"><i class="icon-address-book"></i>Customers</a>
```

then

```
$('a.customers').click()
```

Comment: You're amazing. Thank you so much.. I'm relatively novice obviously, but every bit helps. Thanks again Arun.

Comment: @JamesHolz sorry what do you mean